# Fokker-Planck confusion

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

So, I understand that solving the Fokker-Planck / Kolmogorov Forward equation gives the time-dependent probability density $p(x,t)$ in 1-D let's say.

My question is, how do you use this? Let's say, I wanted to find the probability of a particle being at a position $x = a$, at time $t = \tau$, how would you calculate this from $p(x,t)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be $0$, for a specific $x$.

But you can find the probability that the particle will be located in $[a-\delta/2;a+\delta/2]$ by integrating the equation.

Comment: Okay. thanks. But, that interval you cite is a spatial interval, I believe. How do you deal with the time variable in the integration?

Comment: @ThomasMoore For each $t$ you have a different PDF